# Powerapps - unable to get response from Flow

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I am building a PowerApp that triggers a PowerAutomate flow.

Upon the trigger, the PowerAutomate flow runs successfully. I have set it up so it ends with a 'Respond to a PowerApp or flow' action so that I can return variables into PowerApps.

However, in PowerApps, it seems that nothing is returned.

Here is the code to trigger the flow. It should set 'Success'(PowerApp variable) to the value of 'success'(PowerAutomate output)

```
Set(Success,
    testflow.Run(
        input1,
        input2
    ).success
);
```

The flow runs successfully and returns `success=True`

[image]

However, when I evaluate the variable, we see that it remains empty suggesting that the output from PowerAutomate was empty.

[image]

Any idea why this is so? I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now.

Thank you!

Comment: you have to set flow().success. You need to select the result variable

Comment: Yes, with testflow.Run(input1, input2).success, the result variable success is selected.

Comment: perfect let me add thiis as answer, please accept and upvote it. Shall give me some points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was going wrong. It turns out the fields were passed from Flows to PowerApps, just that they were of the incorrect format so PowerApps never populated the variable.

So even if I define a variable as Boolean earlier in the flow, I cannot just pass it through the 'Respond to a PowerApp or flow' action as a variable. I need to redefine it as a Boolean within the action for it to work.

I kind of understand the logic but it's pretty unintuitive by Microsoft since on the Flows side everything is fine.

Following picture shows some testing I did.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `.success`.

**Also try the following:**

```
ClearCollect(colResponse,
    testflow.Run(
        input1,
        input2
    ).success
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add `flow().success` and this shall give your your result variable with it's value.

For your case it shall be

```
 testflow.Run(input1, input2).success
```